# c# Custom control click event

Tags: c#

I've made a custom control and I want to add a click event so when the user clicks anywhere on the control it will return the position of where the user has clicked on the control. For example if the user clicks in the middle of the bar it would essentially return me enough information for me to calculate 50% and that the user has clicked in the middle.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;

namespace CustomRangeBar
{
    public partial class RangeBar : UserControl
    {
        public RangeBar()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            label1.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            this.ForeColor = SystemColors.Highlight; // set the default color the rangeBar
            this.Click += new EventHandler(RangeBar_Click); 
        }

        protected float percent = 0.0f; // Protected because we don't want this to be accessed from the outside
        // Create a Value property for the rangeBar
        public float Value
        {
            get
            {
                return percent;
            }
            set
            {
                // Maintain the value between 0 and 100
                if (value < 0) value = 0;
                else if (value > 100) value = 100;
                percent = value;
                label1.Text = value.ToString();
                //redraw the rangeBar every time the value changes
                this.Invalidate();
            }
        }
        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);
            Brush b = new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor); //create brush that will draw the background of the range bar
            // create a linear gradient that will be drawn over the background. FromArgb means you can use the Alpha value which is the transparency
            LinearGradientBrush lb = new LinearGradientBrush(new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height), Color.FromArgb(255, Color.White), Color.FromArgb(50, Color.White), LinearGradientMode.Vertical);

            // calculate how much has the rangeBar to be filled for 'x' %
            int width = (int)((percent / 100) * this.Width);
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(b, 0, 0, width, this.Height);
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(lb, 0, 0, width, this.Height);
            b.Dispose(); lb.Dispose();
        }

        private void RangeBar_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // maintain the label in the center of the rangeBar
            label1.Location = new Point(this.Width / 2 - 21 / 2 - 4, this.Height / 2 - 15 / 2);
        }

    }
}

public void RangeBar_Click(object obj, EventArgs ea)
{
    // This get executed if the pictureBox gets clicked
    label1.text = "Increment 1";
}
```

Comment: override the OnClick() method

Comment: where or how do i do that?

Comment: Why don't you use `using` to dispose `b` and `lb` in your `OnPaint` method?

Comment: If you have skype i can show you it in action. I wouldn't mind getting our input on making sure what i'm doing is correct.

@ScottChamberlain I get this error when using the override onClick: Error 1 Method must have a return type

Comment: @JokerMartini Well that is because the example David gave you is wrong, it is missing a return type and a parameter.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Great I got it working just fine now. Were you interested in me showing you the tool I'm writing? I wouldn't mind some feedback.

Comment: No I am not interested, and it is not appropriate IMHO to ask that on here.

Comment: no worries, that's fine. Thank you for your help very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OnClick is not a good function to override or subscribe to because it does not tell you the position where the click happened which is what you are looking for.

What you want is [OnMouseClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onmouseclick%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which includes the x,y of the click point.

```
protected override void OnMouseClick(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    int x = e.X;
    int y = e.Y;

    //Do your calculation here.
}
```